# .htaccess rewrite but keep start URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have main domain, for example, domain1.com. Also I have domain2.com which is addon domain, and I want to redirect domain2.com to domain.com?parameter=value, which is basically domain1.com, but with another template, but that path in URL stays same, domain2.com, not domain1.com. .htaccess file is created inside addon domain directory (public_html/domain2.com), and I have these two lines:

```
RewriteCond % ^domain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain1.com?parameter=value [P]
```

Rewrite works, but URL in browser changes to domain1.com, also I need to rewrite all request, that comes to domain2.com and www.domain2.com. Now only request that com to non-www domain works, but URL in browser changes.

EDIT: U have this code to .htacces, but URL change to domain1.com, instead  to stay domain2.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain1\.com\/\?parameter\=value" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `domain2/.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1  [R,L,QSA]  
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  http://domain1.com/$1 [R,QSA,NC]
```